# Quick Sort Algorithm: Thread 1 EXC Bad Access (code=2)

Tags: c++, c++17

I am having a problem with my quick sort algorithm.  It seems to run correctly when the "cout" statements are uncommented, or while debugging, but otherwise, it usually (but not always) gives me a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)" error.  Does anyone know how to fix this? I thought at first that it was the random number generator, but it continued happening even after I de-randomized the partition pivot.

The main parts of the code are the two functions titles "Partition" and "Q_Sort".  "Switch" just swaps element locations inside partition, "Rand" generates a random integer, and "Disp" just displays the vector. 
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//Display vector
void Disp(vector<double> vect){
    if (vect.size() == 1){
        cout << "{" << vect[0] << "}" <<endl;
    }
    else if(vect.size() < 1){
        cout << "{" << "}" <<endl;
    }
    else{

        for (int ii = 0; ii < vect.size(); ii++) {
            if (ii == 0) {
                cout << "{" << vect[ii] << ", " << flush;
                continue;
            }
            if (ii == vect.size() - 1) {
                cout << vect[ii] << "}" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            cout << vect[ii] << ", " << flush;
        }
    }

}
//Random integer
int Rand(int range){
    srand((unsigned) time(0));
    int r = rand() % range;
    return r;
}

//Switch
void Switch(vector<double> &vect,int switcher ,int switchee){
    if(switchee != switcher){
        int old = vect[switchee];
        vect[switchee] = vect[switcher];
        vect[switcher] = old;
    }
}

//Partition
tuple<int,int,int,int> partition(vector<double> &vect, int around, int start, int end){
//    cout<<"Around: " <<around<<endl;

    double num = vect[around];
    Switch(vect,around,start);
    int i = start;
    int j = start + 1;
    int m = start;
    int mj = start;
    while(j < end){
//        cout<<endl;
        if(vect[j] >= num){
            if(vect[j] == num){
                Switch(vect, mj + 1, j);
                mj +=1;
            }
            j += 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if(vect[j] < num){
            Switch(vect,mj + 1, j);
            Switch(vect,m,mj + 1);
            mj += 1;
            m += 1;
            j += 1;
        }
    }
//    cout<<"End update : "<<endl;

    return {m,mj,j - 1,i};
}


void Q_sort(vector<double> &vect,int around, int start, int end){


    auto [mm, mmjj, jj, ii] = partition(vect,around, start, end);
//    cout<<"Left "<<endl;
    // LEFT

    int startL = ii; // startL = 0;
    int endL = mm ;
//    cout<<endl<< "New vector "<<endl;

//    Disp(vect);
//    cout<<"end "<< endL<<endl;
//    cout<<"start "<< startL<<endl;
    if(endL - startL > 0){

        int r = Rand(endL - startL) + startL;

        Q_sort(vect, r,startL,endL);
    }

    //RIGHT
    int startR = mmjj; //+ 1;
    int endR = jj;
//    cout<<"Right "<<endl;
//    cout<<endl<< "New vector "<<endl;
//    Disp(vect);
//    cout<<"end "<< endR<<endl;
//    cout<<"start "<< startR<<endl;
//    
    if (endR - startR> 1){
        int r = Rand(endR - startR) + startR;
        Q_sort(vect,r,startR,endR + 1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<double> x{1,5,3,5,4,7,2,14,7,14,4};
    Q_sort(x, 0, 0, x.size());

    Disp(x);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this code:

It [worked](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uoK9u25KC3s2p5As) for me. (The seeder was causing the problem probably.)

Compile it with `-std=c++1z` or higher. (PS: Sorry, I forgot to notice the C++17 tag, you will probably be doing this only).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Display vector
void Disp(vector<double> &v) {
    cout << "{";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == v.size() - 1)
            cout << v[i];
        else
            cout << v[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

// Random integer
int Rand(int range) {
    return (rand() % range);
}

// Switch
void Switch(vector<double> &v, int x, int y) {
    if (x != y)
        swap(v[x], v[y]);
}

// Partition
tuple<int, int, int, int> partition(vector<double> &v, int around, int start, int end) {
    auto num = v[around];
    Switch(v, around, start);
    int i, j, m, mj;
    i = j = m = mj = start;
    while (++j < end) {
        if (v[j] >= num) {
            if (v[j] == num)
                Switch(v, ++mj, j);
            continue;
        } else if (v[j] < num) {
            Switch(v, ++mj, j);
            Switch(v, m++, mj);
        }
    }
    return {i, m, mj, --j};
}

// Quick sort
void Q_sort(vector<double> &v, int around = 0, int start = 0, int end = -1) {
    if (end == -1) end = v.size();
    auto [startL, endL, startR, endR] = partition(v, around, start, end);
    if (endL - startL > 0) {
        int r = Rand(endL - startL) + startL;
        Q_sort(v, r, startL, endL);
    }
    if (endR - startR > 1) {
        int r = Rand(endR - startR) + startR;
        Q_sort(v, r, startR, endR + 1);
    }
}

// Driver function
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); // seeder should be called only once during execution
    vector<double> x = {1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 14, 7, 14, 4};
    Q_sort(x);
    Disp(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.  In mine, I commented out the seeder, and it worked perfectly.  Do you know why that was the issue?  Earlier, I removed the call to the random integer as a trouble shooting measure, and it still occurred.  Also, why did the cout statements and the debugger have an impact on whether it ran correctly when the seeder was in the Rand function instead of the main?

Comment: @RahelMiz It was merely a co-incidence that you code was working. It worked when I first ran it! It was later throwing segmentation fault. It happens mostly because of accessing out of range values. But I am not able to figure out the reason yet (I know why it happened but not where). Something unexpected may still be persisting in your code. I just ran the modified code for about 35 times with different vectors and found it working so I posted it as answer. I will update it once I figure out the reason.

Comment: See the same code working like a charm. Run it 2-3 times, you'll get core dumped. https://wandbox.org/permlink/D2VCaiQ1j4yciGAT . Such co-incidences happen because each time each variable occupies memory at a difference place. Sometimes the index that you were accessing was there on free region, and the other times it was messing up with other variables' memory and hence giving error.

Comment: @RahelMiz I tried using `vector::at` instead of `operator []`, hoping that it should throw an out of range exception while accessing, but that even that didn't throw any exception, simple the program caused a segmentation fault. Probably somewhere something is going wrong. Better you should figure it out yourself or try cleaning the algorithm and analyse the corner-cases.